# Neural network for weather forcast?

Tags: neural-network, data-mining, prediction, weather

I have to finish a final project in data mining course. Does it make sense that I want to predict the weather using neural network? I want to use today's weather data to predict the next day's event such as raining and thunderstorm. I am afraid the teacher will say we can see the weather report everyday and this prediction is useless.

Comment: The prediction "same as yesterday" is hard to beat unless you have *really* good data. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say about your teacher, I just can propose for you some way how to make weather forecast better. As usually weather forecast is made by analysis of movement of clouds, winds, speed of movement and then forecast is calculated by human according to some algorithm. But if you want to make some predictions with neural network, you can use data at this web site: http://www.wunderground.com. And let's say, you want to predict weather in city A. The weather in that city depend from what happens around that city ( wind, cloud masses, period of year, time of day, etc. ). So in order to predict weather in city A, you can feed in NN weather in cities around city A. And more cities, or even countries around city A you feed in NN, the more chances of better forecast to receive you have. And if you'll provide enough data into NN, then more chances, that your NN will outperform standard weather report.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a study on how difficult it may be, what can you do to help understand the problem better, improve it and suggest further studies. This is what typically is expected from a project like yours.

I assume this will not be a regression problem, but a classification problem. I would study the prediction performance of chosen features such as temperatures of various time slices in the past, same for amount of clouds, type of clouds, etc. In case you need more, just go out, look into the sky, feel the weather and inspire yourself ;)

And try to use more classifiers, such as SVM, RBF and build upon your conclusions. Best of luck!